# MVC (newbie question): How do you set the default value for a View during a Create action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, entity, default, models

Questions:

1. How do you set default values on a Model when that default value
   is based on the User.Identity.Name?
2. How do you make a field
   read-only on a View but still have it work as intended at the Model
   level

Below is my attempt at both of those issues.

Background:

Each Account can create a bunch of Users.  I want the Account holders to be able to create Users, but I want the Account value to default to their AccountName (unchangeable).  The model will also be used by Admin Accounts, who is able to set the AccountName, so I want to keep that variable on the Model and Views.

Right now my model takes in an optional AccountName param so that I can set it to the User.Identity.Name:

```
public partial class User
{

    public User()
    {
        this.Games = new HashSet<Game>();
    }

    public User(string AccountName)
    {
        this.AccountName = AccountName;
        this.Games = new HashSet<Game>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Account Name")]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public string Rank { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
}
```

The controller then sets the default value for the new user on Create:

```
    // GET: /User/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        User user = new User(User.Identity.Name);

        return View(user);
    }
```

On the View, I changed the @Html.EditorFor to @Html.DisplayFor since I don't want the users to edit that field:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountName)
    </div>
```

The problem is AccountName is a required field, so when I try to save, it will throw a validation error telling me it's required.  I can easily keep that field as an EditorFor field and make that field readonly through javascript, but I wanted to know how this is suppose to be done.

Comment: What else do you capture on the view?  Have you tried using a view model to capture the user data and only supplying what the view needs based on the user data.  So the ViewModel might contain a Name and account name which is passed to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple thoughts:

1. Is AccountName really required by the user? I would say it is not since you are setting it in your controller.  Thus remove the [Required] attribute and add the User user = new User(User.Identity.Name); to the action method that is handling the POST and that solves that problem.  Alternatively you could use @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AccountName) but that leaves you vulnerable to someone changing the value using firebug or some other tool.  In that case you could encrypt/decrypt the value, but seems easier to just manually set it in the post method and you don't have to worry as much about the security of someone maliciously changing the value.
2. To display the value you could just use @Model.AccountName rather than the lambda

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(User model)
   {
       if(!ModeState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

       model.AccountName = User.Identity.Name;  //Probably want to do some check to make sure this isn't null;

       // Create User in the system here...        
       return View(); // Send them to another page 
    }
   ```

Comment: The AccountName is more of a dynamic default value.  I can avoid it on the View for regular users, but it's needed for Admin users.  Is it better to just create two models?  I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: When you say it is more of a dynamic default value what do you mean?  How do you determine the value?  If you are meaning that by default a user cannot change it but an Admin can then I think that goes into more of a permissions issue.  In that case it is probably better to have one screen that is for admins and one screen that is for users and restrict access to the admin page.  If you are trying to have them on the same screen I would be weary as someone could probably find a way to breach your security and set their own account name.